# How do I create an XY Controller like UI in WPF

Tags: wpf

I am looking for something like this.

I should be able to drag the co-ordinate around inside the XY graph with a mouse. The position of the co-ordinate determines the X and Y values.

Is there a readily available control I can reuse? If not, how do I go about writing one?

[image: I am looking for something like this]

Answer (score 4):

I haven't seen any control like this, i guess you'll have to code it yourself.
There's a few things here to implement, and I'll talk about the graph portion only.
First, you should define a checklist of how this control is supposed to behave (i.e. move lines with cursor only when mousebutton is down), after that is done...well, that's the fun part!

**EDIT** : OK, now here's a rough Version, and when I say rough, I mean it. I put it into a window rather than a user control, you can just copy paste it into your control. This has many flaws and should be used productively only after fixing all issues that occur.Also, you have to be careful when mixing pixel design with flexible/relative design like Stretch-Alignment. I restricted this to pixel precision by making the window non-resizable.

```
<Window x:Class="graphedit.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    x:Name="window"
    MouseMove="Window_MouseMove"
    Height="400" Width="400"
    ResizeMode="NoResize">
<Canvas x:Name="canvas"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Canvas.Background>
        <RadialGradientBrush>
            <GradientStop Color="#333333" Offset="1"></GradientStop>
            <GradientStop Color="#666666" Offset="0"></GradientStop>
        </RadialGradientBrush>
    </Canvas.Background>
    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,1"
            BorderBrush="White"
            Margin="0,0,0,0"
            Width="{Binding Path=Point.X}"
            Height="{Binding Path=Point.Y}"></Border>

    <Border BorderThickness="1,1,0,0"
            BorderBrush="White"
            Margin="{Binding Path=BottomRightBoxMargin}"
            Width="{Binding Path=BottomRightBoxDimensions.X}"
            Height="{Binding Path=BottomRightBoxDimensions.Y}"></Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="1"
            BorderBrush="White"
            Margin="{Binding Path=GripperMargin}"
            Background="DimGray"
            CornerRadius="4"               
            Width="10"
            x:Name="gripper"
            MouseDown="gripper_MouseDown"
            MouseUp="gripper_MouseUp"
            Height="10"></Border>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Point.X}" Canvas.Left="174" Canvas.Top="333" Width="42"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Point.Y}" Canvas.Left="232" Canvas.Top="333" Width="45"></TextBox>
    <TextBlock Foreground="White" Canvas.Left="162" Canvas.Top="336">X</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Canvas.Left="222" Canvas.Top="336" Foreground="White" Width="13">Y</TextBlock>
</Canvas>
```

The code-behind looks like the following:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace graphedit
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isDragging;

    private Point mousePositionBeforeMove;

    private Point point;

    public Point Point
    {
        get { return this.point; }
        set
        {
            this.point = value;
            this.InvokePropertyChanged(null);
        }
    }

    public Thickness BottomRightBoxMargin
    {
        get
        {
            Thickness t = new Thickness()
                          {
                              Left = this.Point.X,
                              Top = this.Point.Y
                          };
            return t;
        }
    }

    public Thickness GripperMargin
    {
        get
        {
            Thickness t = new Thickness()
            {
                Left = this.Point.X - 5,
                Top = this.Point.Y - 5
            };
            return t;
        }
    }

    public Point BottomRightBoxDimensions
    {
        get
        {
            return new Point(this.Width - this.Point.X,
                             this.Height - this.Point.Y);
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Point = new Point(100, 80);
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void InvokePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventArgs args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name);
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, args);
        }
    }

    private void gripper_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.isDragging = true;
        this.mousePositionBeforeMove = e.GetPosition( this.canvas );
    }

    private void gripper_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.isDragging = false;
    }

    private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(this.isDragging)
        {
            Point currentMousePosition = e.GetPosition( this.canvas );
            double deltaX = currentMousePosition.X - this.mousePositionBeforeMove.X;
            double deltaY = currentMousePosition.Y - this.mousePositionBeforeMove.Y;

            double newPointX = (this.Point.X + deltaX < 0 ? 0 : (this.Point.X + deltaX > this.Width ? this.Width : this.Point.X + deltaX)) ;
            double newPointY = (this.Point.Y + deltaY < 0 ? 0 : (this.Point.Y + deltaY > this.Width ? this.Width : this.Point.Y + deltaY)) ;

            this.Point = new Point(newPointX,newPointY);
            this.mousePositionBeforeMove = currentMousePosition;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can have a look at the charting library [DynamicDataDisplay](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/). It's a library created as a research project by Microsoft (afaik) and might provide the functionality you are looking for.

First, reference the DynamicDataDisplay dll in your project and then create the following namespace in your xaml:

```
xmlns:d3="http://research.microsoft.com/DynamicDataDisplay/1.0"
```

Then you can add a `ChartPlotter` object to the xaml and strip everything you don't need from it (axes, legend, ...). You can use the `CursorCoordinateGraph` to track the mouse. If you want to change the layout etc, you could use a `VerticalRange` object.

```
    <d3:ChartPlotter Width="500" Height="300" 
                     MainHorizontalAxisVisibility="Collapsed" 
                     MainVerticalAxisVisibility="Collapsed"
                     LegendVisibility="Collapsed" NewLegendVisible="False"> 
        <!--This allows you to track the mouse-->       
        <d3:CursorCoordinateGraph x:Name="cursorGraph"/>
        <!-- this range does nothing more then make the background gray,
             there are other ways to achieve this too-->
        <d3:VerticalRange Value1="-300" Value2="300" Fill="Gray"/>
    </d3:ChartPlotter>
```

If you want to track the position of the mouse, you can either use code-behind:

```
Point current = cursorGraph.Position;
```

or bind the `Position` property to your viewmodel:

```
<d3:CursorCoordinateGraph x:Name="cursorGraph" Position="{Binding CurrentMousePosition}"/>
```

If you want to actually fix the position when you click, I guess you'll have to create a new `CursorCoordinateGraph` in the OnClick or MouseClick event handler for the `ChartPlotter` and calculate the Point and provide it for the new Graph:

```
//pseudo code!!!
mainGraph.DoubleClick += HandleDoubleClick;

private void HandleDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e){
    //get position from current graph:
    var position = cursor.Position;
    //you have to calculate the "real" position in the chart because 
    //the Point provided by Position is not the real point, but screen coordinates
    //something like cursor.TranslatePoint(cursor.Position, mainGraph);
    var newCoord = new CursorCoordinateGraph { Position = position };
    mainGraph.Children.Add(newCoord);
}
```

You might have some work to make it look like you want to. I suggest you browse through the samples provided on the codeplex page and have a look at the discussion page. This library is huge and has a lot of possibilities, but provides little actual documentation though...

Hope this points you in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

I've made demo of my simple reusable ControllerCanvas control. Hope it will help you. You can set all properties in your XAML.

**ControllerCanvas.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace XYControllerDemo
{
    public class ControllerCanvas : Canvas
    {
        #region Dependency Properties

        public Point Point
        {
            get { return (Point)GetValue(PointProperty); }
            set 
            {
                if (value.X < 0.0)
                {
                    value.X = 0.0;
                }

                if (value.Y < 0.0)
                {
                    value.Y = 0.0;
                }

                if (value.X > this.ActualWidth)
                {
                    value.X = this.ActualWidth;
                }

                if (value.Y > this.ActualHeight)
                {
                    value.Y = this.ActualHeight;
                }

                SetValue(PointProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty PointProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Point", typeof(Point), typeof(ControllerCanvas), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Point(),
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.SubPropertiesDoNotAffectRender));

        public Brush ControllerStroke
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(ControllerStrokeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ControllerStrokeProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ControllerStrokeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ControllerStroke", typeof(Brush), typeof(ControllerCanvas), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Red,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.SubPropertiesDoNotAffectRender));

        public double ControllerStrokeThickness
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(ControllerStrokeThicknessProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ControllerStrokeThicknessProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ControllerStrokeThicknessProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ControllerStrokeThickness", typeof(double), typeof(ControllerCanvas), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1.0,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.SubPropertiesDoNotAffectRender));

        public Brush GridStroke
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(GridStrokeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GridStrokeProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty GridStrokeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("GridStroke", typeof(Brush), typeof(ControllerCanvas), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.LightGray,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.SubPropertiesDoNotAffectRender));

        public double GridStrokeThickness
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(GridStrokeThicknessProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GridStrokeThicknessProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty GridStrokeThicknessProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("GridStrokeThickness", typeof(double), typeof(ControllerCanvas), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1.0,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.SubPropertiesDoNotAffectRender));

        public bool GridVisible
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(GridVisibleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GridVisibleProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty GridVisibleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("GridVisible", typeof(bool), typeof(ControllerCanvas), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.SubPropertiesDoNotAffectRender));

        public Thickness GridMargin
        {
            get { return (Thickness)GetValue(GridMarginProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GridMarginProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty GridMarginProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("GridMargin", typeof(Thickness), typeof(ControllerCanvas), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Thickness(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.SubPropertiesDoNotAffectRender));

        public double GridSize
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(GridSizeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GridSizeProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty GridSizeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("GridSize", typeof(double), typeof(ControllerCanvas), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(30.0,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.SubPropertiesDoNotAffectRender));

        #endregion

        #region Drawing Context

        Pen penGrid = null;
        Pen penController = null;

        Brush previousGridStroke = null;
        double previousGridStrokeThickness = double.NaN;
        double penGridHalfThickness = double.NaN;

        Brush previousControllerStroke = null;
        double previousControllerStrokeThickness = double.NaN;
        double penControllerHalfThickness = double.NaN;

        Point p1 = new Point();
        Point p2 = new Point();
        Point p3 = new Point();
        Point p4 = new Point();

        double width = double.NaN;
        double height = double.NaN;

        void DrawGrid(DrawingContext dc)
        {
            width = this.ActualWidth;
            height = this.ActualHeight;

            // draw vertical grid lines
            for (double y = GridMargin.Top; y <= height - GridMargin.Bottom; y += GridSize)
            {
                p1.X = GridMargin.Left;
                p1.Y = y;
                p2.X = width - GridMargin.Right;
                p2.Y = y;

                GuidelineSet g = new GuidelineSet();
                g.GuidelinesX.Add(p1.X + penGridHalfThickness);
                g.GuidelinesX.Add(p2.X + penGridHalfThickness);
                g.GuidelinesY.Add(p1.Y + penGridHalfThickness);
                g.GuidelinesY.Add(p2.Y + penGridHalfThickness);
                dc.PushGuidelineSet(g);
                dc.DrawLine(penGrid, p1, p2);
                dc.Pop();
            }

            // draw horizontal grid lines
            for (double x = GridMargin.Left; x <= width - GridMargin.Right; x += GridSize)
            {
                p1.X = x;
                p1.Y = GridMargin.Top;
                p2.X = x;
                p2.Y = height - GridMargin.Bottom;

                GuidelineSet g = new GuidelineSet();
                g.GuidelinesX.Add(p1.X + penGridHalfThickness);
                g.GuidelinesX.Add(p2.X + penGridHalfThickness);
                g.GuidelinesY.Add(p1.Y + penGridHalfThickness);
                g.GuidelinesY.Add(p2.Y + penGridHalfThickness);
                dc.PushGuidelineSet(g);
                dc.DrawLine(penGrid, p1, p2);
                dc.Pop();
            }
        }

        void DrawController(DrawingContext dc)
        {
            width = this.ActualWidth;
            height = this.ActualHeight;

            // draw vertical controller line
            p1.X = 0.0;
            p1.Y = Point.Y;
            p2.X = width;
            p2.Y = Point.Y;

            GuidelineSet g1 = new GuidelineSet();
            g1.GuidelinesX.Add(p1.X + penControllerHalfThickness);
            g1.GuidelinesX.Add(p2.X + penControllerHalfThickness);
            g1.GuidelinesY.Add(p1.Y + penControllerHalfThickness);
            g1.GuidelinesY.Add(p2.Y + penControllerHalfThickness);
            dc.PushGuidelineSet(g1);
            dc.DrawLine(penController, p1, p2);
            dc.Pop();

            // draw horizontal controller line
            p3.X = Point.X;
            p3.Y = 0.0;
            p4.X = Point.X;
            p4.Y = height;

            GuidelineSet g2 = new GuidelineSet();
            g2.GuidelinesX.Add(p3.X + penControllerHalfThickness);
            g2.GuidelinesX.Add(p4.X + penControllerHalfThickness);
            g2.GuidelinesY.Add(p3.Y + penControllerHalfThickness);
            g2.GuidelinesY.Add(p4.Y + penControllerHalfThickness);
            dc.PushGuidelineSet(g2);
            dc.DrawLine(penController, p3, p4);
            dc.Pop();
        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
        {
            base.OnRender(dc);

            // create ord update grid pen
            if (penGrid == null)
            {
                penGrid = new Pen(GridStroke, GridStrokeThickness);

                previousGridStroke = GridStroke;
                previousGridStrokeThickness = GridStrokeThickness;

                penGridHalfThickness = penGrid.Thickness / 2.0;
            }
            else
            {
                if (GridStroke != previousGridStroke || GridStrokeThickness != previousGridStrokeThickness)
                {
                    previousGridStroke = GridStroke;
                    previousGridStrokeThickness = GridStrokeThickness;
                    penGrid.Brush = GridStroke;
                    penGrid.Thickness = GridStrokeThickness;

                    penGridHalfThickness = penGrid.Thickness / 2.0;
                }
            }

            // create ord update controller pen
            if (penController == null)
            {
                penController = new Pen(ControllerStroke, ControllerStrokeThickness);

                previousControllerStroke = ControllerStroke;
                previousControllerStrokeThickness = ControllerStrokeThickness;

                penControllerHalfThickness = penController.Thickness / 2.0;
            }
            else
            {
                if (ControllerStroke != previousControllerStroke || ControllerStrokeThickness != previousControllerStrokeThickness)
                {
                    previousControllerStroke = ControllerStroke;
                    previousControllerStrokeThickness = ControllerStrokeThickness;
                    penController.Brush = ControllerStroke;
                    penController.Thickness = ControllerStrokeThickness;

                    penControllerHalfThickness = penController.Thickness / 2.0;
                }
            }

            // drag grid
            if (GridVisible)
            {
                DrawGrid(dc);
            }

            // draw controller
            DrawController(dc);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Mouse Events

        protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsMouseCaptured)
            {
                this.Point = e.GetPosition(this);

                this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
                this.CaptureMouse();
            }

            base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
        }

        protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.IsMouseCaptured)
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
                this.ReleaseMouseCapture();
            }

            base.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.IsMouseCaptured)
            {
                this.Point = e.GetPosition(this);
            }

            base.OnMouseMove(e);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="XYControllerDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XYControllerDemo"
        Title="XYControllerDemo" Height="410" Width="680">
    <Grid>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <local:ControllerCanvas x:Name="controller1" 
                                Margin="10" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" 
                                Background="Transparent" Width="300" Height="300" 
                                GridMargin="0,0,0,0" GridVisible="True" GridSize="30" 
                                GridStroke="LightGray" GridStrokeThickness="1.0"
                                ControllerStroke="Red" ControllerStrokeThickness="1.0"
                                Point="50,50"/>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10" Width="100" 
                 Text="{Binding ElementName=controller1, Path=Point, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

        <local:ControllerCanvas x:Name="controller2" 
                                Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
                                Background="Transparent" Width="300" Height="300" 
                                GridMargin="0,0,0,0" GridVisible="True" GridSize="30" 
                                GridStroke="LightGray" GridStrokeThickness="1.0"
                                ControllerStroke="Blue" ControllerStrokeThickness="1.0"
                                Point="90,250"/>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" Width="100" 
                 Text="{Binding ElementName=controller2, Path=Point, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace XYControllerDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```